# News-Window (Browser or RSS) in Kiosk Mode

Tags: ubuntu, browser, kiosk

We have 242 PCs with Ubuntu 12.04 running something like a kiosk mode using [iDesk](http://idesk.sourceforge.net/html/index.html). The background image contains some info for the user but this is very static.
Currently we are searching for a way to display dynamic infos to our users without the need to modify the background image.

So I think about a simply program which shows a windows with dynamic content - a website for example. But the window must be without any controls or styles and the user should not be able to move or resize this window.

Is there some program which could help to get this?

This is a screenshot of the current (blurred) screen. At the bottom I want to add something like a box with dynamic content:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I use a python script which runs a simple QWebKit window. This is the code I'm currently using (maybe I find some further improvements). (uses some snippets from Stackexchange)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *


class NewsWindow(QWebView):

    def __init__(self):
        super(NewsWindow, self).__init__()

        # reload timer
        self.reloadtimer = QtCore.QTimer()
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.reloadtimer, QtCore.SIGNAL("timeout()"), self.reloadtimerRun)
        self.reloadtimer.start(1000*60*10) # run every 10 mins

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(245, 824, 790, 200)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.load(QUrl("http://URL..."))
        self.show()

    # Hide context menu
    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = QMenu(self)

    def reloadtimerRun(self):
        self.reload()


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = NewsWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```